# Autofac sorting using metadata

Tags: .net, autofac

I'm trying to resolve an IEnumerable of my dependencies through Autofac, but I need to be able to sort them somehow. Thought I'd use the Autofac's metadata to achieve that, but I can not make it work:

This is the registration code:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
    .AssignableTo<IDiscoverable>()
    .As<IDiscoverable>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithMetadata<DisplayOrderAttribute>(c => c.For(x => x.Order, ???));
```

So in the question mark I need to map the value to an attribute on my class.

```
[DisplayOrder(5)]
public class Test : IDiscoverable
{
}

[DisplayOrder(1)]
public class Test : IDiscoverable
{
}
```

So that when I resolve them, I'm able to get a sorted collection:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(IEnumerable<Meta<IDiscoverable>> discoverables)
    {
       //sort it using metadata here
       var sortedDiscoverables = discoverables.Sort(x => x.Order).Select(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

Anyway to achieve that in Autofac?

*[Update]* I can do the following and using untyped metadata, but can't seem to find a way to do it using a typed metadata object.

```
.WithMetadata("Order", x => x.GetAttribute<DisplayOrderAttribute>().Order);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata in Autofac is stored on registrations as an `IDictionary<string, object>` where the key is the metadata name and the value is the metadata value. This is defined on the `Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration` interface.

Regardless of which extension you use - `WithMetadataFrom<TAttribute>` (normally used when working with attributes) or `WithMetadata` (when you're directly specifying metadata) - it all boils down to string/object pairs.

Which means **you won't be able to get "strongly typed metadata" as far as the item key is concerned**. You'll always have to work in strings.

Aside: If you used `WithMetadataFrom` you wouldn't have to put the lambda in there to select the Order property from your metadata attribute. `WithMetadataFrom` automatically grabs the values of readable attribute properties and adds them to the dictionary.